# Dynamic population of SQL in Java from array with nulls

Tags: java, sql, database, vectorwise

To give a simple example of my problem:

```
//Create database table allowing nulls.
CREATE TABLE test(one int not null, two int null, three int not null);
```

Now, in Java I have an array of objects matching the database content.  I need to create an insert/update/delete statement for this database table using the array values.

```
Object[] arr = { 4, null, 1 };
String sql = GenereateInsert(arr);
```

This gets difficult though because I need to leave out null fields from the insert in advance.  E.g. if **two** above is not null:

```
 INSERT INTO test(4, 2, 1);
```

everything is easy.  But if it is null, I need the statement to be:

```
 INSERT INTO test(one, three) values(4, 1);
```

The tables I'm dealing with are 50 columns and up, so I don't want to do this manually, it will be unmanageable.  So, how do people address this problem in general?  It must be a common situation.

PS: I don't want to use a full ORM library, that seems like overkill.

Comment: Have you considered creating a stored procedure that accepts a table as a parameter? (not sure if Java supports this, just throwing it out there)

Comment: I would recommend that you use a class to represent the fields in your table instead of an array as it will greatly increase the readability in comparison to using an array!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest something like this:

1. Run a query like `SELECT * FROM <TABLE_NAME> LIMIT 1`. Use the [`ResultSetMetaData`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) to retrieve the columnNames and their columnType. Store it in a HashMap and the keys in a ArrayList
2. Now create a `PreparedStatement` using the keys from the ArrayList as the columnNames. *I guess that would not be hard to do*
3. Now given your data in the array, the fact that you know what SQL type they're from the HashMap, you can easily use this information to map the values that you get from your array in the `?` of your generated PreparedStatement.

Now the question is how to deal with `null`. Well since you know the type of column, if the value that you get is `null` then you can use [`PreparedStatement.setNull(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull%28int,%20int%29) to set them as null.

Also, just wanted to point out that [according to this document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/preparedstatement.html), there's an important guide to the *setXXX(...)* of JDBC:

> **6.1.5    Sending JDBC NULL as an IN parameter**
>
> The setNull method allows a programmer to send a JDBC NULL (a generic
>   SQL NULL) value to the database as an IN parameter. Note, however,
>   that one must still specify the JDBC type of the parameter.
>
> A JDBC NULL will also be sent to the database when a Java null value
>   is passed to a setXXX method (if it takes Java objects as arguments).
>   The method setObject, however, can take a null value only if the JDBC
>   type is specified.

This would imply that you can send *null* as the value for the parameter of your `setXX(...)` method and you really not have to call the `setNull(..)` method explicitly.

I hope this works for you!

Comment: Would the ResultSetMetaData provide column names for columns that were null in the result?

Comment: @w00te: Yes. Since you're doing a `Select * from...`, it would fetch all the columns.

Comment: @w00te: Sure, give it a try. I had an almost similar issue in which I came up with this solution. I'm guessing it would work for you as well :) :)

Answer (score 1):

A high-level algorithm:

1. Store an array of the column names (in same order as input parameters) - let's call this `allColumnNames` - as a field of the class.
2. When the method is called, create two new, empty `List<String>`s, one to represent the column names, one to represent the values - let's call these `columnNamesList` and `columnValuesList`.
3. Iterate over the input array, for each non-null element, add `allColumnNames[i]` to `columnNamesList` and `values[i]` to the `columnValuesList`.
4. Build your insert statement by concatenating together `INSERT INTO tablename`, a comma-separated list of each of the values in `columnNames`, `VALUES`, and a comma-separated list of each of values in `columnValuesList`.

Comment: The number of columns that a table has cannot be changed at runtime! Why take the overhead of constructing a query at runtime when you can use a PreparedStatement?

Comment: Because the array passed to the method *is* changing at runtime, or at least I assume so, therefore sometimes different columns will need to be specified in the INSERT. Although if your suggestion is to use PreparedStatement.setNull(), that makes a lot of sense too.

Comment: Thanks :) I'm going to play with these two options and see how they work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about other database sytems, but in postgres you can insert a null value as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
  id       SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  val1     INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
  val2     INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
  val3     INTEGER DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test(val1, val2, val3) VALUES(DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT);
```

You can also do set statements in the same way:

```
UPDATE test SET val1 = DEFAULT, val2 = 123, val3 = DEFAULT WHERE id = 3;
```

Thus,

```
Stringbuilder sqlStmt = new StringBuilder();
sqlStmt.append("INSERT INTO test(val1, val2, val3) VALUES(");
sqlStmt.append(((val1 == null) ? "DEFAULT" : val1.toString()));
sqlStmt.append(" , ");
sqlStmt.append(((val2 == null) ? "DEFAULT" : val2.toString()));
sqlStmt.append(" , ");
sqlStmt.append(((val3 == null) ? "DEFAULT" : val3.toString()));
sqlStmt.append(";");
statement.execute(sqlStmt.toString());
```

If you had a lot of these, it might make more sense to do it with a for-each loop.

Comment: That looks interesting, I'll give that a try too :)

Comment: This works with Ingres/VectorWise as well. The only difference is that INGRES uses a different syntax for specifying identity field...